# jQuery Validate trigger only one custom method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to trigger only one specific custom validation? Let's say I have three custom validation methods:

```
$.validator.addMethod('customValidation1', function (data)
{
 }, 'Error');
$.validator.addMethod('customValidation2', function (data)
{
 }, 'Error');
$.validator.addMethod('customValidation3', function (data)
{
 }, 'Error');
```

Insted of calling all of them, how can I trigger just `customValidation1` without triggering `customValidation2` and `customValidation3`.

Calling something like this`$("#id").valid();` is triggring all of them.

Comment: Your scenario is impossible as presented. Rules must be assigned to fields, otherwise, no rules are used.  It would be impossible for all three rules to be called on one field unless you assigned all three rules to that one field.  This is a poorly written question because it's lacking enough code to reproduce the issue. Please review the FAQ section about posting good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Quote OP:

> calling something like this `$("#id").valid();` is triggering all of them.

I don't see how that is possible.  Did you somehow assign all three custom rules to the `#id` field?  Otherwise, fields can not automatically pick up any of your custom rules without a programmatic declaration.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myform").validate({  // <-- initialize plugin on the form.

        rules: {
            field_name: {  // <-- this is the name attribute, NOT id
                required: true,
                customValidation2: param  // <-- declare custom rule on this field
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Let's assume that the field with the `name="field_name"` also has `id="field_name"`.

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" id="field_name" />
```

Calling something like `$("#field_name").valid()` will only evaluate the `customValidation2` method along with any other rules or methods as declared in the `.validate()` example above.